# Not receiving a angular router param value passed from one component to another component?

Tags: angular, typescript, router

Here is my routes in app.module.ts file
Look at the `{path: 'category/:id/:maxPrice', component: ProductListComponent},`

```
/** Define the routes */
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'selling/:id', component: ProductUpdateComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'selling', component: SellingComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'sell-item', component: SellItemComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'help', component: HelpComponent},
  {path: 'contact-us', component: ContactUsComponent},
  {path: 'about-us', component: AboutUsComponent},
  {path: 'login/callback', component: OktaCallbackComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'orders-history', component: OrdersHistoryComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'members', component: MembersPageComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'checkout', component: CheckoutComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'cart-details', component: CartDetailsComponent},
  {path: 'products/:id', component: ProductDetailsComponent},
  {path: 'search/:keyword', component: ProductListComponent},

  {path: 'category/:id', component: ProductListComponent},
  {path: 'category/:id/:condition', component: ProductListComponent},
  {path: 'category/:id/:maxPrice', component: ProductListComponent},
  

  {path: 'category', component: ProductListComponent},
  {path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

This is the function where i am passing categoryId and maxPrice param value:

1. const url is the router url
2. this.currentCategories = categoryId
3. this.sliderValue = maxPrice

```
  /**
   * 
   */
  onPriceSliderChange() {

    this.resetConditionFilter();

    console.log("Slider Value: " + this.sliderValue);


    const url = `/category/${this.currentCategories}/${this.sliderValue}`;

    console.log("slider url: " + url);
    
    this.router.navigateByUrl(url);

  }
```

This is the function where i am trying to receive the categoryId and maxPrice param value that has been passed from onPriceSliderChange() function:
I get the categoryId but maxPrice value is missing

```
/**
   * Get list of products by product category id through productService
   * And store the data to products list 
   * Support Pagination
   */
  handleListProducts() {

    // check if "id" parameter is available for category id
    const hasCategoryId: boolean = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('id');

    // check if "condition" parameter is available for product condition
    const hasCondition: boolean = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('condition');

    // check if 'maxPrice' parameter is available for max price selected from price range slider 
    //const hasMaxPrice: boolean = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('maxPrice');
    const hasMaxPrice: boolean = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('maxPrice');
    

    // debugging
    
    console.log("category id: " + hasCategoryId);
    console.log("max price: " + hasMaxPrice);


    // if Id is available 
    if (hasCategoryId) {
      // get the "id" param string. convert string to a number using the "+" symbol
      this.currentCategoryId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    } 

    
    // check if condition is available
    if (hasCondition) {
      // get the "condition" param string. 
      this.condition = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('condition');
    } 


    // check if max price is available 
    if (hasMaxPrice) {
      // get the "maxPrice" param string. 
      this.maxPrice = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('maxPrice');

      console.log("category id: " + this.currentCategoryId);
      console.log("max price: " + this.maxPrice);
    }

    //
    // Check if we have a different category than previous
    // Note: Angular will reuse a component if it is currently being viewed
    // 

    // if we have a different category id than previous
    // then set thePageNumber back to 1
    if (this.previousCategoryId != this.currentCategoryId) {
      this.thePageNumber = 1;
    }

    this.previousCategoryId = this.currentCategoryId;


    // Angular Pagination component: pages are 1 based
    // Spring Data REST: pages are 0 based

    if (hasCategoryId && hasCondition) {

      this.productService.getProductsByCondition(this.condition,
                                                  this.currentCategoryId,
                                                  this.thePageNumber - 1,
                                                  this.thePageSize)
                                                  .subscribe(this.processResult());

    } else if (hasCategoryId && hasMaxPrice) {

      console.log("id: " + this.currentCategoryId + "price: " + this.maxPrice);

      this.productService.getProductByPriceRange(this.currentCategoryId,
                                                  0,
                                                  this.maxPrice,
                                                  this.thePageNumber - 1,
                                                  this.thePageSize)
                                                  .subscribe(this.processResult());
    
    } else { 

      // Now get the products for the given category "id"
      this.productService.getProductListPaginate(this.thePageNumber - 1,
                                                  this.thePageSize,
                                                  this.currentCategoryId)
                                                  .subscribe(this.processResult());

    } 
      
 

  }
```

My Components:

This is the ProductCategoryMenuComponent where I am sending the maxPrice value from:

```
import { Options } from '@angular-slider/ngx-slider';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductCategory } from 'src/app/common/product-category';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-category-menu',
  templateUrl: './product-category-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-category-menu.component.css']
})
export class ProductCategoryMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  // list of product category to display on category menu
  productCategories: ProductCategory[];

  currentCategories: number = 1;

  sliderValue: number = 500;

  options: Options = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: 500
  };

  

  constructor(private productService: ProductService,
              private router: Router,) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.listProductCategories();
  }

  /**
   * get list of product categories
   */
  listProductCategories() {
    
      this.productService.getProductCategories().subscribe(
        data => {
          
          this.productCategories = data; // set data to productCategories array
        }
      );


  }


  /**
   * Get current categories
   * @param categoryId 
   */
  getCurrentCategories(categoryId: number) {
    this.currentCategories = categoryId;
    
    
    // reset condition and price filter when catgory is changed
    this.resetConditionFilter();

    this.resetPriceSlider();
    
  }


  /**
   * 
   */
  resetConditionFilter() {

    // reset product condition radio button
    const newElement = document.getElementById("new") as HTMLInputElement;
    newElement.checked = false;

    const usedElement = document.getElementById("used") as HTMLInputElement;
    usedElement.checked = false;


  }



  /**
   * 
   */
  resetPriceSlider() {

    this.sliderValue = 500;
  }



  /**
   * 
   * @param condition 
   */
  onCondition(condition: string) {

    

    if(condition === 'New') {

      const url = `/category/${this.currentCategories}/New`;
      
      this.router.navigateByUrl(url);

    } else if (condition === 'Used') {

      const url = `/category/${this.currentCategories}/Used`;

      this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
    }


  }


  /**
   * 
   */
  onPriceSliderChange() {

    this.resetConditionFilter();

    console.log("Slider Value: " + this.sliderValue);


    const url = `/category/${this.currentCategories}/${this.sliderValue}`;

    console.log("slider url: " + url);
    
    this.router.navigateByUrl(url);

  }
  


}
```

This is ProductListComponent where I am trying to get the maxPrice param value:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { CartItem } from 'src/app/common/cart-item';
import { Product } from 'src/app/common/product';
import { CartService } from 'src/app/services/cart.service';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';

/**
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */


@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[] = []; // products list
  currentCategoryId: number = 1; // current category Id
  previousCategoryId: number = 1; // previous category Id
  searchMode: boolean = false; // search mode to see if any search has been done.

  condition: string;
  
  maxPrice: number;


  // New properties for pagination
  thePageNumber: number = 1;
  thePageSize: number = 12;
  theTotalElements: number = 0;

  previousKeyword: string = null;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private cartService: CartService) { }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(() => {
      this.listProducts();
    });
    
  }

  

  /**
   * Get list of products by product category id through productService
   * And store the data to products list 
   */
  listProducts() {

    // check to see if any parameter has been passed from searchComponent
    this.searchMode = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('keyword');


    // check if searchmode is true
    // If true then handle search products
    // else return products list
    if(this.searchMode) {
      this.handleSearchProducts();
    } else {
      this.handleListProducts();
    }

    // after reloading the component move to top of the page.
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }




  /**
   * get list of products based on search keyword
   */
  handleSearchProducts() {
    
    // get the keyword that has been passed by searchComponent
    const theKeyword: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('keyword');


    // if we have a different keyword than previous
    // then set thePageNumber to 1

    if (this.previousKeyword != theKeyword) {
      this.thePageNumber = 1;
    }

    this.previousKeyword = theKeyword;

    console.log(`keyword=${theKeyword}, thePageNumber=${this.thePageNumber}`);

    // now search for the products using keyword
    this.productService.searchProductListPaginate(this.thePageNumber - 1,
                                                  this.thePageSize,
                                                  theKeyword).subscribe(this.processResult());

  }




  /**
   * Get list of products by product category id through productService
   * And store the data to products list 
   * Support Pagination
   */
  handleListProducts() {

    // check if "id" parameter is available for category id
    const hasCategoryId: boolean = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('id');

    // check if "condition" parameter is available for product condition
    const hasCondition: boolean = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('condition');

    // check if 'maxPrice' parameter is available for max price selected from price range slider 
    //const hasMaxPrice: boolean = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('maxPrice');
    const hasMaxPrice: boolean = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('maxPrice');
    

    // debugging
    
    console.log("category id: " + hasCategoryId);
    console.log("max price: " + hasMaxPrice);


    // if Id is available 
    if (hasCategoryId) {
      // get the "id" param string. convert string to a number using the "+" symbol
      this.currentCategoryId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    } 

    
    // check if condition is available
    if (hasCondition) {
      // get the "condition" param string. 
      this.condition = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('condition');
    } 


    // check if max price is available 
    if (hasMaxPrice) {
      // get the "maxPrice" param string. 
      this.maxPrice = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('maxPrice');

      console.log("category id: " + this.currentCategoryId);
      console.log("max price: " + this.maxPrice);
    }

    //
    // Check if we have a different category than previous
    // Note: Angular will reuse a component if it is currently being viewed
    // 

    // if we have a different category id than previous
    // then set thePageNumber back to 1
    if (this.previousCategoryId != this.currentCategoryId) {
      this.thePageNumber = 1;
    }

    this.previousCategoryId = this.currentCategoryId;


    // Angular Pagination component: pages are 1 based
    // Spring Data REST: pages are 0 based

    if (hasCategoryId && hasCondition) {

      this.productService.getProductsByCondition(this.condition,
                                                  this.currentCategoryId,
                                                  this.thePageNumber - 1,
                                                  this.thePageSize)
                                                  .subscribe(this.processResult());

    } else if (hasCategoryId && hasMaxPrice) {

      console.log("id: " + this.currentCategoryId + "price: " + this.maxPrice);

      this.productService.getProductByPriceRange(this.currentCategoryId,
                                                  0,
                                                  this.maxPrice,
                                                  this.thePageNumber - 1,
                                                  this.thePageSize)
                                                  .subscribe(this.processResult());
    
    } else { 

      // Now get the products for the given category "id"
      this.productService.getProductListPaginate(this.thePageNumber - 1,
                                                  this.thePageSize,
                                                  this.currentCategoryId)
                                                  .subscribe(this.processResult());

    } 
      
 

  }



  /**
   * Map data from JSON response to property defined in this class and assign data to their properties
   */ 
  processResult() {
    return data => {
      this.products = data._embedded.products;
      this.thePageNumber = data.page.number + 1; // Spring Data rest page are 0 based & Angular page are 1 based.
      this.thePageSize = data.page.size;
      this.theTotalElements = data.page.totalElements;

    }
  }


  /**
   * Update the page size selected by user
   * @param pageSize 
   */
  updatePageSize(pageSize: number) {
    this.thePageSize = pageSize;
    this.thePageNumber = 1;
    this.listProducts();
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param product 
   */
  addToCart(product: Product) {

    console.log(`Adding to cart: + ${product.name}, ${product.unitPrice}`);

    // 
    const theCartItem = new CartItem(product);

    this.cartService.addToCart(theCartItem);

    
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using router navigate, can pass values from one component to another as below
while passing values from onPriceSliderChange

```
 this.router.navigate(['/category', { id: categoryId, maxPrice:maxPriceValue}]);
```

**in ngOnIt at receiver**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._route.params.subscribe((params) => {
       this.currentCategoryId = params['id'];      
       this.maxPrice = params['maxPrice']);     
    })
```

Comment: Thank You. This solved the problem. Do you know why my way didn't work?